# how do you create a function that calculates confidence intervals given the value of 1 - a (alpha)?

Tags: r, function, confidence-interval

I am fairly new to r, so I apologize in advance.

The main problem with my coding is that I only know how to code for the function given a 95% confidence interval, so I was wondering if there was a way where you can input a number in for "level=" that is not 95% and still get a confidence interval.

here is my coding:

```
blah <- function(x1,x2,level=0.95){

  n1 <- length(x1)

  n2 <- length(x2)

  s1 <- sd(x1)


  s2 <- sd(x2)

  CI <- (s1^2 / s2^2) / qf(c(.975,.025), df1 = n1-1, df2 = n2-1)

  return(list("95% CI"=CI))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try,

```
library(scales)

blah <- function(x1,x2,level=0.95){
  
  n1 <- length(x1)
  
  n2 <- length(x2)
  
  s1 <- sd(x1)
  
  
  s2 <- sd(x2)
  
  CI <- (s1^2 / s2^2) / qf(c((1+level)/2,(1-level)/2), df1 = n1-1, df2 = n2-1)
  
  
  text <- paste0(scales::percent(level), " CI")
  return(setNames(list(CI), text))
  
  
}

blah(c(1:10), c(11:20), .95)
$`95% CI`
[1] 0.2483859 4.0259942

blah(c(1:10), c(11:20), .90)
$`90% CI`
[1] 0.3145749 3.1788931
```